# Залил новое фото на сайт, но при перезагрузке всё ещё отображается старое фото, сделал Command + Shift + R всё стало Ок

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookie, localstorage

Может ли это быть связанно с тем что где-то кешируется эта картинка и пока не почистишь куки и т.д то она не сменится на обновленную?

Comment: чтобы протолкнуть  картинку через кеш броузеров, нужно поменять у неe url. Например изменить в нем путь или изменить/добавить параметр. Если оригинальный url: `https://example.com/assets/pic.png`, то изменить его можно как `https://example.com/assets/pic2.png` или `https://example.com/assets/pic.png?v=1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, браузер активно кеширует контент. Чтобы избежать подобного поведения, стоит к ссылкам на изображения добавлять рандомные "хвосты". Например так:

```
<img src="path/to/image.png?{$randomint}" />
```

Comment: это хорошо но только при разработке. на боевом сайте лучше так не делать